# SQL Server 2016: create credential and add SQL Server Agent proxy for it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to script a [creation of SQL Server identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql) to be then used to execute SQL Server agent jobs via a proxy.

It looks as though I can only use a Windows account and thence I would have to provide its password in plain text. Seriously? There must be a better way to do this. I need this script to work on my team-mates' machines as well as mine:

```
USE [msdb]

CREATE LOGIN [proxy_login] WITH PASSWORD=N'passw0rd', 
    DEFAULT_DATABASE=[SSISConfig], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

CREATE CREDENTIAL [my_cred] WITH IDENTITY='proxy_login', SECRET='passw0rd'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_proxy 
    @proxy_name=N'My_Proxy',
    @credential_name=N'my_cred', 
    @enabled=1
```

**Error**:

> Msg 14720, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_credential_identifiers, Line 69 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   The operation failed because credential '@credential_name' identity is not a valid Windows account

In ideal world I would like to use the `SYSTEM_USER` login for the credential without having to supply their password.

Answer (score 3):

> The operation failed because credential '@credential_name' identity is
>   not a valid Windows account

That is because you did not use Windows account, but SQL Server account, that is wrong. You just misunderstand [SQL Server Agent Proxies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx)

> **SQL Server Agent proxies use credentials to store information about
>   Windows user accounts**.  The user specified in the credential must have
>   "Log on as a batch job" permission on the computer on which SQL Server
>   is running.
>
> SQL Server Agent checks subsystem access for a proxy and gives access
>   to the proxy each time the job step runs.  If the proxy no longer has
>   access to the subsystem, the job step fails.  Otherwise, SQL Server
>   Agent impersonates the user that is specified in the proxy and runs
>   the job step.

In your cited article there is this phrase that you did not read carefully:

> A credential is a record that contains the authentication information
>   that is required to connect to a resource outside SQL Server.

That is, `CREDENTIAL` for Agent is some account to access OS(Windows) resources, so it's `Windows account`, OS does not know nothing about your SQL Server logins. The permissions to Windows resources are granted to Windows accounts, and one of this account you can use as a proxy for Agent.

Comment: And if you want a TSQL job step to run as a particular user, Agent will impersonate the job owner, and if the job owner is a sysadmin it can specify an arbitrary user to impersonate.